# bottom-aligning items with Genesis Grid Plugin

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox

I'm using Genesis and a child theme on my WordPress site, and I just installed the Genesis Grid plugin for my category pages. Each category will display two posts per row that are aligned at the top. But because my titles are all different lengths, the photos typically don't line up with each other in a row. I'm thinking bottom-aligning the teasers would fix this problem.

I'm trying to use a flexbox, and I can't get the code to work. Right now I have this:

```
.teaser {
display: flex !important;
-webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

I've tried adding elements like align-self: flex-end; vertical-align: auto; and margin-top: auto;, but I'm still struggling. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: That you are using WordPress or Genesis doesn't matter. I would remove those tags and provide enough code so others can reproduce the problem. That is the entire code minus non-essentials in jsbin or another place or here on SO. You will actually get answers that way, otherwise I doubt it.

Comment: When you're in column-direction in flexbox, vertical alignment is controlled with `justify-content`. Your `align-self: flex-end` would move the item to the right. So try `justify-content: flex-end`.